# Is there a better way to keep your own copy of a customized open source project?

Tags: version-control

I use an open source project to host a site (OrchardCMS) which is available in a GIT repository via CodePlex. I have made a few customizations to the source code that are specific to my implementation and I want to keep preserved and under source control. However the challenge arises when there's a new release of the source engine.

My changes certainly won't go into the blessed repository everyone uses.

Currently I'm using two repositories. I use the CodePlex OrchardCMS repository to get the latest changes from the engine the community uses (and that I contribute some bug fixes to).

I then have my own copy which contains my changes. For this, I am using my own source control ([hosted TFS from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/team-foundation-service)). When an update to the core engine comes out, I XCOPY all the files from the current source to my self-maintained repository and commit them to my project.

However this seems like there should be a better option. Any opinions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git` to have an alternative solution.

You can clone the `git` main repo and keep it updated with the new relases, and you can keep your local modifications, that aren't to be shared with anyone, on a local branch.

When a new release came out, you simply update your `master` branch in your `git` repo an then you can `rebase` or `merge` your local modications on top of it.

Comment: Thanks... I'm not terribly familiar with GIT just yet and local repositories so I need to dig in with what you suggested.

One concern ... the idea isn't just for my source control for my changes to leverage version control but also to provide for a backup of my changes. With a local only repository, that defeats that purpose, right?

Comment: There are a lot of nice git tutorials on the web, starting from the [official one](http://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial) to the nice [git school](http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1)

Comment: If you keep a single local repo, you should do your backups in some way. Git is a distributed CMS so you can `push` your modification to some central `git` repo making avaible to other developers.