# Merge changes from an external git repo into my local branch

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I asked a similar question [here recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001788/is-there-a-better-way-to-keep-your-own-copy-of-a-customized-open-source-project), but this is a more specific question.

I've cloned a open source project locally (OrchardCMS) & created a local branch (**accom.dev**) off a tag "1.6" in the origin/master branch in order to add my own tweaks to the codebase.

They have since made a lot of changes to the codebase, moving from 1.6 to 1.7 onto 1.7.1 and have even more commits (the current release is 1.7.1). What I want to do is take everything from the 1.7.1 tag (including everything that goes back to 1.6) and merge it into my local branch. From there I will address conflicts, fix my customizations and then deploy to my website.

*Note this is NOT a cherry-pick as I want everything from 1.6 up to 1.7.1 merged into my local branch, BUT I don't want the stuff that has been committed SINCE the 1.7.1 release. **IOW, I want my customizations to be based off the official 1.7.1 release, not on more recent stuff**.*

I'm pretty sure what I did gives me what I want, but I'm not sure if there was a better way:

1. Switched back to to the **origin/master**
2. Created a new local branch **1.7.1-release** from the point where the 1.7.1 tag was created... *this is treated as a temp branch because I couldn't figure out how to do a merge from a specific point*
3. Switched back to my **accom.dev** branch
4. Merged the **1.7.1-release** branch into my **accom.dev** branch
5. Addressed conflicts & committed the changes in **accom.dev**
6. Deleted the **1.7.1-release** branch

At this point I am where I want to be, but I'm wondering if there was an easier way...

Comment: What you did looks like the right approach. The only way I can think of making it easier is realizing that you don't really have to merge a branch. You could have done `git merge refs/tags/1.7.1` instead of steps 1-4 above...

Comment: This worked like a champ... didn't know about "refs" as a keyword. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way is as follows (assumes `origin` is the name of your remote and that you have already checked out your accom.dev branch):

```
$ git fetch --tags origin
From ...
* [new tag]    some-tag -> some-tag
* [new tag]     ...

$ git merge some-tag
```

Comment: So this would first get all tags local (which I can already see in the gitextensions browser) and then do a merge straight from a tag?